# I need action bar search view in a custom adapter listview

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-search

In my app, there is a listview with textview and image, I can search element by adding a edittext in xml, but I want search bar in action bar.. how can I do this? please help..
    [Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2cPX.png)

```
      // My activity java code

productName = new String[] { "Baby Item", "Harbal Item", "Medicine Item", "Electronics Item", "Product item 1",
        "Product item 2", "Product item 3", "Product item 4", "Product item 5", "Product item 6"};

productDescesc = new String[] { "Baby Item description", "Harbal Item description",
        "Medicine Item description", "Electronics Item description", "Product item description",
        "Product item description", "Product item description", "Product item description", "Product item description","Product item description" };

    productIcon = new int[] { R.drawable.baby_item, R.drawable.harbal_item,
            R.drawable.medicine_item, R.drawable.electronics_item,
            R.drawable.demo_product_item, R.drawable.demo_product_item, R.drawable.demo_product_item,
            R.drawable.demo_product_item, R.drawable.demo_product_item, R.drawable.demo_product_item };

    // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    for (int i = 0; i < productName.length; i++)
    {
        SearchProduct searchProduct = new SearchProduct(productIcon[i], productName[i], productDescesc[i]);
        // Binds all strings into an array
        arraylist.add(searchProduct);
    }

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    // Capture Text in EditText
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        });

        //Onclick
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {

//                                Toast.makeText(Search.this,"List Item Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                        .show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Search.this,ProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

//my custom adapter code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<SearchProduct> productList = null;
    private ArrayList<SearchProduct> arraylist;
    SearchProduct searchProduct;
    private ListViewAdapter filter;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           List<SearchProduct> worldpopulationlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.productList = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SearchProduct>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView name;
        TextView desc;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SearchProduct getItem(int position) {
        return productList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgProduct);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            holder.desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.name.setText(productList.get(position).getName());
        holder.desc.setText(productList.get(position).getDesc());

        // Set the results into ImageView
        holder.icon.setImageResource(productList.get(position)
                .getIcon());

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        productList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            productList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (SearchProduct searchProduct : arraylist) {
                if (searchProduct.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    productList.add(searchProduct);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: not solved this problem, But I have use another method... thanks for ur concentration... :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add an EditText in your xml to do that.
What you would like to do is to customise your toolbar.
This link might be of help: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html

So your MainActivity extends your CustomToolBarActivity, and your existing work will be in a fragment.

Comment: when action bar search not working, then I use EditText for bypass the work...
The example you shared is good , but it is not my requirement.. please provide me some code or link.. thank you very much....

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when action bar search not working, then I use EditText for bypass the work..."

That's what you're trying to do, right? Put your search bar in the blue box (referring to your attached image), instead of the EditText below it.

To do that, you need to customise your Toolbar. Like the example in the article.

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/search_toolbar_id"
                android:hint="search_here"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = AppDelegate.getContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_browse_and_search);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    EditText searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar_id);
    // Put in another button(search icon) to do whatever you want with an OnClickListener

    // Put your existing work in a fragment and replace the frame layout with your fragment
    Fragment yourExistingWorkInThisFragment = new Fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, yourExistingWorkInThisFragment)
            .commit();
```